# Windows Search won't find my files since the Anniversary Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

Before Anniversary, I could press Start and then type procmon, and Windows would find "D:\sam\Downloads\SysinternalsSuite\Procmon.exe". If I then hit enter, the program would be launched. This was really fast and convenient.

Since the Anniversary Update, it only offers useless web search suggestions on how to download Process Monitor (that don't even open in my chosen web browser, but that is a separate matter). If I press the 'find results in apps' button at the top of the result window, there are no results. If I press the 'find results in documents' button then it finds procmon.chm, in the same directory, but not the exe.

Needless to say, having to right-click on the search result, and choose 'open containing folder', and then search *again* for procmon.exe and only *then* hitting enter, leaving me with an unwanted File Explorer window clogging up my screen is neither fast nor convenient.

Why is Windows Search so badly broken on my system and how do I fix it?

[edit] Lack of 'Indexing Options' in control panel: [image: Lack of 'Indexing Options' in control panel]

Comment: Is you Indexing service turned on?  Is D: included in the Indexing Options' Location list?

Comment: The Indexing Options control panel has been removed in the Anniversary update. It's not in the Setting app and it's not in the Control Panel. The WSearch service is running.

Comment: It's there, just not obvious. If you tell it to 'view by' Icons instead of Categories it'll be in the list.   Or just search for "Indexing Options" from Start, or in the search box within the Control Panel. Honestly tho, I find the Start Search sucks for finding files you don't use semi-regularly.  But (once the locations are loaded into the Indexing Options) the Search box from within Explorer finds stuff lickity split.

Comment: it's not just you and/or me tho. Start Search just doesn't seem to like including EXEs.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3eu8c8/cant_search_for_exe_files_in_start_menu/, https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1268490-start-menu-search-not-searching-exe-files/, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_cortana/windows-10-search-does-not-index-exe-files/2b451f16-6a0e-49b4-a245-ebfeadf0d82e?auth=1 Seems it may be by design...

Comment: Techie007 - it's not in the list. I've looked in control panel, there is no Indexing Options in icon view, searching for Indexing Options in the top right only gives two results; the first takes me to Explorer's settings, which have nothing to do with search results; and the second takes me to the Windows Search troubleshooter, which fails to work with a useless numeric error code. I remember these options existing pre-Anniversary update, but it seems they have now been removed from Windows 10, leaving Windows Search worthless as a result.

Comment: Which exact version/build are you using? (Run winver)

Comment: 1607 (OS Build 14393.447)

Answer (score 0):

Got to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs. If your shortcuts inside the folders listed there do not have an image it seems to be a problem with ownership. Go to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows and right click "Start Menu" -> Properties -> Security tab -> Advanced -> At the "Owner:" field click Change and type in Everyone and click "Check Names". Everyone should be listed there and click "Ok". Check "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects". Now click on "Everyone" in the list of "Permission entries:" and click on "Edit" and give full permissions. After that make sure you check "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable persmission entries from this object" and click "Apply". Your shortcut icons inside the Programs folder will return and Windows can find all your applications again. I do not know what broke this in the first place. This is how I fixed it on my end.